# How do UNIQUE indexes work on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique

If I add a UNIQUE index on the `email,password` columns, will the index check if:

1. Is `email` unique `AND` is `password` unique, or
2. The combination of `email,password` is unique, as in, it would allow `u1@mail.com, 123` and `u2@mail.com, 123`

Apologies if my thoughts seem abrupt here, I'm having difficulty in expressing them today for some reason. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second answer is the correct one. The combination of the two fields must be unique.

For #1 you would need a separate unique index on each column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @redFilter  the combination is a better option.  But remember that UNIQUE is different that primary key. You can have null values in UNIQUE, if you want to avoid that when you create the table use the "NOT NULL" at the end of each data type.